# how to make a nested tqdm bars on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

Here is an example for nested tqdm bar

```
import time
import tqdm
for i in tqdm.tqdm(range(3)):
    for j in tqdm.tqdm(range(5)):
        print(i," : ", j)
```

I try it on jupyter notebook but it does not show any thing without error! However, it works coorectly on ipython console!

Comment: I came here to post the same question. I have problems with this exact scenario, although my manifestation of the problem is different. Instead of an updating bar, I instead get a new bar printed for every update. So in the code example posted, I would actually have ~15 bars printed right after one another (actually, I think a few more since we get one at a 0 status as well). CORRECTION: I'd get 3 bars since the inner loop is fast enough. Add in a time.sleep(1.5) in the inner loop and then you get the ~15 bars.

Comment: TL;DR: nesting "just works", but in jupyter you need to `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm`.

Answer (score 15):

I just found the solution that I'm going to use. The solution has [plenty of examples here](https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/#ipython-jupyter-integration).

I've modified the example in the original post with both the solution as well as a time delay for visualization purposes (the final output is the same with or without the delay).

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(3)):
    for j in tqdm_notebook(range(5)):
        sleep(0.1)
        print(i," : ", j)

print("Done!")
```

The final output looks like this. While it's processing, it's pleasant to watch at (no jumping around or anything crazy).

[image: Image of the final output after completion]

---

One little hack that I'm now doing to make this a super easy drop-in replacement is to pull in tqdm like this, so I don't have to change any other code:

```
from time import sleep
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(3)):
    for j in tqdm(range(5)):
        sleep(0.1)
        print(i," : ", j)

print("Done!")
```

Comment: About drop-in replacement: they thought about it, and it's `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm` nowadays.

Comment: or even `from tqdm.auto import tqdm`